# How can I put all includes on one page with classes?

Tags: php, class, include, footer

For a school project I need to put all returning code into an include. I want it all on one page, but I can't get it to work. Creating an include is no problem, but I want them all in one PHP page. I have the following code, but it is wrong:

```
//footer
<?php

class footer
{
echo '<a href="login.php">Account</a>';
echo '<a href="subscription.php">Subscription</a>';
echo '<a href="about.php">About us</a>';
echo '<a href="termsofuse.php">Terms of Use</a>';
echo '<small>&copy; 2017, (myname)  &  (name partner)</small>';
}
?>
```

How do I have to modify the code, so that it is correct?

Comment: You can't just put PHP statements directly inside a class definition. If you want to use OO, start with reading up on the basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the html code to variables.

```
<?php $footer = "<a href="login.php">Account</a>
                 <a href="subscription.php">Subscription</a>
                 <a href="about.php">About us</a> 
                 <a href="termsofuse.php">Terms of Use</a>
                 <small>&copy; 2017, (myname)  &  (name partner)</small>"
?>
```

After that you only need to include the one PHP file and `<?php echo $footer ?>` for all parts of your page

Comment: Already got that at the moment, but that would give so much pages. Would be more clean if all includes are on 1 page imo.

Comment: This one looks very nice and clean, same problem as above tho but here I returns: Undefined variable: footer in. This one is definitly clean tho <3

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. You will only declare methods(functions), properties(variables) and constants directly in a class body.
If you want to run echoes, you should declare it inside a method.

An example for your case:

```
class Footer
{
    public static function printLinks()
    {
        echo '<a href="login.php">Account</a>';
        echo '<a href="subscription.php">Subscription</a>';
        echo '<a href="about.php">About us</a>';
        echo '<a href="termsofuse.php">Terms of Use</a>';
        echo '<small>&copy; 2017, (myname)  &  (name partner)</small>';
    }
}
```

Then call it in every place that you want it as:

```
Footer::printLinks(); //This will call all those echoes at once
```

Comment: I like this one and it also works, although it's printing the text: Uncaught Error: Class 'Footers' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\PHP\index.php:120 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in. It's uploading to the server automatically, I even uploaded it manually. Everything works exapt the footer. Not sure what I did wrong here. edit: typo

Comment: You have to include its declaration (<?php include 'Footer.php'; ?>, for example) or use [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Also, your error says you're trying to call "Footers". The correct is "Footer" -without the "s"